# An algorithm for a minimization problem, How to minimize the wasted length of combination of multiple items with different length and number

Tags: algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms

Suppose there is an unlimited number of pipes, each has length $x$ meters.
There is a list of requirements of pipes with shorter length than $x$. The number of these items are also given.

For example we need to have $n_1$ pipes of length $x_1$,$n_2$ pipes of length $x_2$,..., $n_k$ pipes of length $x_k$ $\forall i, x_i \leq x$.

We need to cut the pipes of length $x$ such that the requirements to be fulfilled and also minimize the number of the used pipes.

For example for $x = 12$ and $$item1: x_1=3,n_1=50$$ $$item2: x_2=5,n_2=30$$ $$item3: x_3=7,n_3=80$$$$item4: x_4=2,n_4=90$$$$item5: x_5=9,n_5=15$$

we can cut the pipes in multiple ways. The worst solution is to allocate one pipe for each requirement, in this way the number of used pipes will be $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}{n_i} = 265$$

But by combining `item2` and `item3` into one pipe, we can reduce $256$ by $30$. In this way `item2` is prepared then we can combine `item1`, `item3` and `item4` to prepare the items and use the minimum number of the pipes.

As another solution we can also combine `item5` and `item1`, or even allocate one pipe of length $12$ for $4$ pipes of `item1`

**I would like to know is this a famous problem? and is there any efficient algorithm for it?**

## My Solutions

### Solution 1

Because I really don't know what the class of this problem is, I tried to solve this problem using the approximation algorithm given for the *Set Cover* problem.

The *item*s form the set of elements, and any combination of *item*s where the summation of their $x_i$ is less than or equal to $x$ is a valid set and its cost equals to $$cost(set_i) = x-\sum_{item_j \in set_i}{x_j} $$

But in set cover problem an element may appear in multiple sets while in this problem such thing is not reasonable. Besides that the $n_i$s are different that is why the Set Cover solution is not working here.

### Solution 2

My second solution is a simple greedy algorithm. First I create set of valid sets as explained in the **Solution 1**, select the one with minimum `cost`. In this way at least one `item` with the minimum $n_i$ is produced.

In the second step, first I need to update $n_i$s (because some items are produced in the previous step) and remove the completely covered item from the list. If $set_j$ was the set with minimum cost, Then there will be a few pipes with the length $$wasted= x - \sum_{item_k \in set_j}{x_k}$$.

For the remaining items in the list, if there is anyway to form elements in a set such that sum of their $x_i$ is less than or equal to $wasted$ then we produce those pipes, else we should repeat from the first step with the new list.

Comment: This is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to knapsack problem.

Simple algorithm (not the optimal solution)

1. order the item descending
2. cut the n5/(x\x5) ("\" is integer division, i.e. 12\9=1) = 15 pipes to satisfy x5 = 9m and partially x1

Repeat step 2 for x3 = 7m and so on.

Comment: This is an optimization of Solution 2.